# variable sidea is not being defined? Python programming

Tags: python

In this program I keep getting the error that sidea is not defined even though I am returning it and calling it. I have tried chaning the names of things, but it still does not work. how do I fix this? thanks. The error is coming on the line per = perimeter(sidea, sideb, sidec)
and its NameError: name 'sidea' is not defined

```
import math
import sys
def main():
    x1, y1 = eval(input("\nEnter the coordinates for the points, x1, y1:"))
    x2, y2 = eval(input("Enter the coordinates for the points, x2, y2:"))
    x3, y3 = eval(input("Enter the coordinates for the points, x3, y3:"))

    dist = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    per = perimeter(sidea, sideb, sidec)
    are = area(sidea, sideb, sidec, per)
    vol = volume(area)

    print("\nThe three points are,", x1, y1, "/", x2, y2, "/", x3, y3)
    print("\nThe distance between the points is,", "%0.2f" % (dist))
    print("\nThe perimter of the triangle is,", "%0.2f" % (per))
    print("\nThe area of the triangle is,", "%0.2f" % (are))
    print("\nThe volume of the triangle is,", "%0.2f" % (vol))

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    sidea = (((x2-x1)**2) + ((y2- y1)**2))**(1/2)
    sideb = (((x3-x2)**2) + ((y3- y2)**2))**(1/2)
    sidec = (((x3-x1)**2) + ((y3- y1)**2))**(1/2)
    return sidea, sideb, sidec
    if ((sidea + sideb) < sidec) and ((sidea + sidec) < sideb) and ((sideb + sidec) < sidea):
        print("You cannot create a triangle with these points!")
        (sys.exit())

def perimeter(sidea, sideb, sidec):
    perimeter = sidea + sideb + sidec
    return perimeter

def area(sidea, sideb, sidec, perimeter):
    hp = perimeter / 2
    area = (hp*((hp-sidea)*(hp-sideb)*(hp-sidec)))**(1/2)
    return area

def volume(area):
    h = eval(input("Enter a positive number for the height of the triangle:"))
    if h > 0:
        volume = area * h / 3
        return volume
    else:
        print("The number entered for the height is not positive!")
        (sys.exit())

main()
```

Comment: 1. Please fix your indentation. 2. Using eval on user input is a *horribly* bad idea. 3. No, you haven't defined sidea in main().

Comment: can you elaborate on how i didnt define sidea please

Comment: Well, can you point to the part where you think you did define it?

Comment: Also, the `if` statement in `distance()` will never be reached - you probably wanted to place it before the `return` statement. Also, you don't need all those parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not returned `sidea`, you have returned a tuple and in that tuple is your `sidea` variable:

```
dist = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
```

But your `distance` function returns:

```
return sidea, sideb, sidec
```

Adjust the first line to be like this:

```
sidea, sideb, sidec = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
```

This will properly unpack the variables for your use.

Comment: ok thans, but no im getting typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int' on the line volume = area * h / 3

Comment: Of course you are: `vol = volume(area)`. You define the variable you want to use as `are` in the line before this. Instead, you are passing the function `area` to `volume`. Pass your variable, not your function.